# Autocomplete-Python not working, ATOM, Error from jed, grammer 3.9.txt not found

Tags: python-3.x, autocomplete, atom-editor, jedi

I upgraded my python version from 3.8 to 3.9. I was using autocomplete-Pythonn extension. And an error came in my atom editor. That grammer3.9.txt not found.

**Looks like this error originated from Jedi. Please do not report such issues in autocomplete-python issue tracker. Report them directly to Jedi. Turn off outputProviderErrors setting to hide such errors in future. Traceback output:**
*Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\hp.atom\packages\autocomplete-python\lib\jedi\parser_*init*_.py", line 56, in load_grammar
return _loaded_grammars[path]
KeyError: 'C:\Users\hp\.atom\packages\autocomplete-python\lib\jedi\parser\grammar3.9.txt'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\hp.atom\packages\autocomplete-python\lib\completion.py", line 376, in watch
self._process_request(request)
File "C:\Users\hp.atom\packages\autocomplete-python\lib\completion.py", line 338, in *process_request
script = jedi.api.Script(
File "C:\Users\hp.atom\packages\autocomplete-python\lib\jedi\api_*init**.py", line 126, in **init**
self.*grammar = load_grammar(version='%s.%s' % sys.version_info[:2])
File "C:\Users\hp.atom\packages\autocomplete-python\lib\jedi\parser_*init**.py", line 58, in load_grammar
return _loaded_grammars.setdefault(path, generate_grammar(path))
File "C:\Users\hp.atom\packages\autocomplete-python\lib\jedi\parser\pgen2\pgen.py", line 393, in generate_grammar
p = ParserGenerator(filename)
File "C:\Users\hp.atom\packages\autocomplete-python\lib\jedi\parser\pgen2\pgen.py", line 18, in **init**
stream = open(filename)
**FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\hp\.atom\packages\autocomplete-python\lib\jedi\parser\grammar3.9.txt'**

I came up with this error last time. But then I Just renamed the file grammer3.7 to grammer3.8. But I do not think this is the right way to do so.

Comment: This usually happens when parso or Jedi are outdated. So please just try to upgrade those.